# Unexpected GC behaviour: some data always going into the tenure generation

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Ran a very simple code to try to see how garbage collectors function.

```
String a = null;
while ( true ) {
  a = new String(" no... ");
}
```

I am using ParallelGC. I printed GC results and here is the first (minor) GCs.

```
[GC [PSYoungGen: 16448K->1616K(19136K)] 16448K->1624K(62848K), 0.0022134 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]
```

youngGen came down by `14880K`
however fullHeap came down by just `14872K`

Does this mean 8k has moved to the tenure generation? My understanding is the GC might have been called some instanced of class 'a' must have been marked alive and moved to the tenure generation. Is this understanding correct? Also, is this "[Floating Garbage](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html#cms.floating_garbage)"? Overtime the tenure generation does get filled up and a fullGC is required, however it does take awhile.

Also, in this particular case, shoudln't the entire minor collection get collected and ideally nothing goes into the tenure generation? All these are short lived objects.

Answer (score 2):

You've got 1 instance of String alive when the GC is in progress (the strong reference inside the while loop) so that one is the one that survives hence the 8k.

In this case I wouldn't call the String ref floating garbage. Floating garbage is when an object wasn't ready to be GCed when the GC checked it, but was ready by the time the GC finished. An example of that would be.

```
Thread1:    Person p = new Person("sammy")

    Thread2:    gc runs and sees that the Person instance is reachable through p.

Thread1:    p = null; // This Person instance is now unreachable.

    Thread2:    GC finishes. The person instance could have been collected but was reachable at the time the collector checked it.
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your measurement is accurate.

First, when a GC occurs, the Eden is wiped and surviving objects goes in Survivor space. So in your case, this explains why the YoungGen goes from 16448K to 1616K : Those 1616K are the survivor's occupancy.

Meanwhile, the total heap occupancy after GC is 1624K, which means that the old generation indeed contains 8K of data.

The term "Floating Garbage" refers to CMS collections, where newly-dead objects are not catched by the collector. It does not apply with ParallelGC.

As for your test case, the String objects will never go in Old Generation. They will at most survive 1 GC cycle and go to a Survivor space, and then will be reclaimed

Hope that helps !

Comment: thanks. if string objects never go into Old Generation, why does the heap (slowly but steadily) get full after which a full GC is required. What do you think is filling up he old gen?

Comment: There are at least 20 other threads running in the JVM, not only your "Main" Thread, so it is quite logical that some objects are created. Example : the Timer threads or the GC threads itself. The important thing is that after a full GC, you reclaim a lot of memory.

Comment: @N.M. As a sidepoint, note that Pierre said that the Strings objects in your example won't go into old gen, not that string objects in general never go into old.